# Data binding: One vs two way

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I don't currently have an example for my question. I would just like to get some insight of the following : When should one use one or two way data binding in XAML ?

Thank you in advance for the time you take to answer this !

Comment: [Binding.Mode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.mode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  and [BindingMode Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingmode(v=vs.110).aspx) In summary: use `OneWay` if the property is readonly, use `TowWay` if you want to change it from your view.

Comment: Oh gee, that sounds really simple ! Thank you for the insight, you should write an answer and I'll check it as the answer for my query ! @Bolu

Comment: Assuming you've read about [data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it is very unclear what you are looking for here. Indeed you use one way when you need one way binding and twoway when you need updates both ways... So what exactly you are looking for with this question?

Comment: Currently, I'm in the process of learning my way around XAML/UI/MVVM. I read a bit on the web but was wondering when I should use which or even if I needed to use them while creating a Windows Phone Application

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In summary: use `OneWay` if the property is readonly, use `TowWay` if you want to change it from your view.

> - TwoWay updates the target property or the property whenever either    the target property or the source property changes.
> - OneWay updates    the target property only when the source property changes.

REF：[Binding.Mode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.mode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  and [BindingMode Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingmode(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Use OneWay if you only want to update the view from your model.

TwoWay also updates the model if you change the view. e.g. a TextBox. So you should use it when you want that your view can affect the model.

[MSDN-Page BindingMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingmode(v=vs.110).aspx)